# Is there a common method for measuring "curviness" of a line?

Tags: postgis, geometry, gps, trajectory

I have a bunch of GPS tracks in a Postgres+PostGIS database and want to extract a single metric as a measure of turns shown in the data. Some of the GPS targets travel in almost straight lines while others do some curves. The curves are sometimes all right/left hand turns but most of the time it's just squiggles. I've tried to use the length of the line vs the distance between start/end, or area covered by the convex hull but these aren't perfect.

Can you think of a function that would be able to determine the "curviness" of a linestring and could, possibly, differentiate between straight lines, regular turns, or random paths?

[This paper](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1262244) makes mention of taking the sums of the delta in bearing for each vertex but I was wondering whether PostGIS has something built in that would make it easier.

There's no guarantee that any GPS track would be complete, cover a set time period, have the same length etcetc

Here are some examples of the GPS tracks:

[image]

[image]

Comment: One measure is **Sinuosity**

Comment: Sinuosity: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33041/calculating-path-sinuosity-in-postgis

Comment: See here how to identify "curved" and "straight" parts of a line using a concept that makes it possible to tweeked using two parameters: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397907/88814

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One measure is Sinuosity which is the line length divided by the shortest distance from the line start and end points:

```
select id, 
       st_length(geom)/st_distance(st_startpoint(geom), st_endpoint(geom)) as sinuosity, 
       geom
from test.testlines
```

The values will range from 1 to infinity, 1 for straight lines:

[image]

Comment: Good to have a name for the ratio. It does seem like I would then need 2 metrics to meet my needs. Sinuosity for curvy/not curvy and something else for regular vs not regular turns. Any ideas on the second?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will be of great use to you, it might be too specific, but I have a function that tests for what I call **cutbacks** in lines.  This is where a line bends more than a certain amount of degrees.

First create a new type:

```
create type cutback_flag as (hascutbacks bool, cutbackgeom geometry);
```

Then create the cutback function - you will need to adjust the degree ranges to use the threshold you want.  Currently it flags bends greater than 90 degrees (more than a right angle bend, an acute angle rather than obtuse).  The function returns `true` if there is a cutback in the source geometry and also returns a point at the cutback:

```
create or replace function flag_cutbacks(g geometry)
returns cutback_flag language plpgsql as $$
declare
    numpoints int;
    cutbackgeom geometry;
    hascutbacks bool;
    r cutback_flag;
begin
    select st_numpoints(g) into numpoints;
    for i in 1..numpoints loop
        if  degrees(st_angle(st_pointn(g,i+1),st_pointn(g,i),st_pointn(g,i-1),st_pointn(g,i))) between 0 and 90
            or degrees(st_angle(st_pointn(g,i+1),st_pointn(g,i),st_pointn(g,i-1),st_pointn(g,i))) between 270 and 360 then
            hascutbacks := true;
            cutbackgeom := st_collect(cutbackgeom, st_pointn(g,i));
        end if;
    end loop;
    select hascutbacks, st_union(cutbackgeom) into r;
    return r;
end; $$;
```

Use the function:

```
select (flag_cutbacks(geom)).*, id, geom from super_awesome_geometry_table;
```